# Testing the state updates of a wai application

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, hspec, haskell-spock

I have an application written on top of [Wai](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai), configured to have some custom state and be testable with [Test.Hspec.Wai](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-wai-0.10.1/docs/Test-Hspec-Wai.html).

I can test request/response interactions, but I haven't been able to figure out how to test for state changes; specifically, if my application state is a `TVar Text`, how do I get the value out of it inside the test, in order to verify its value?

```hs
-- app :: TVar Text -> IO Application
-- is defined in my application library

wrapp :: Text -> IO (TVar Text, Application)
wrapp s = do
  s' <- newTVarIO s
  a <- app s'
  return (s', a)

spec :: Spec
spec = withState (wrapp "hello") $ do
  describe "x" $ it "x" $ do
      st <- getState -- st is TVar Text.
      s <- undefined -- WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO GET THE STATE OUT OF TVar?
      get "/" `shouldRespondWith` "\"hello, world!\""
      s `shouldBe` "hello"
```

---

<sup>*) Note that the `getState` method I'm talking about here is not exported in the latest LTS at the time of writing; add hspec-wai-0.10.1 to `extra-deps` to get a version that has all the features mentioned here.</sup>

Comment: I think, you did right, only got confused with types. What's `st` in your case? Does `stuff` really accept that?

Comment: @arrowd Yeah, confused with types is exactly my problem, I guess. The `st` in my question is just the wording from the Hspec-Wai documentation; it's not really clear to me what it is, or should be, for it to work. `stuff` is a getter on my state type (my state is basically `type MyState = MyState { stuff :: Maybe Text }`, so _if_ I manage to tell the test what my state type is correctly, then it should work.

Once I have this working, I'm also going to want to modify my state to be a `TVar MyState`, so that might complicate things I guess... :/

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you forgot to wrap whole your `spec` into `with app`, like it is done in `hspec-wai`s README:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = with app $ do
  describe "GET /" $ do
    it "responds with 200" $ do
      get "/" `shouldRespondWith` 200
```

Comment: Note that in my original snippet I do have `with app`, but not at the top-level of the stack. If I have to move it there, how do I control the initial state of the app?

Comment: I re-worded the question and provided a shorter code sample of what I'm trying to do; would you mind taking another look?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.5.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TVar.html#v:readTVarIO this?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't compile; it gives me a type mismatch, expecting a `WaiSession a b` (don't remeber the exact types of `a` and `b` now, but can check when I get home) but getting an `IO Text`

Comment: `WaiSession` is an instance of `MonadIO`, so you can use `liftIO` to turn `IO` into `WaiSession`.